# How can I recover files after running "git clean -df" by accident?

Tags: git, terminal, data-recovery, git-clean

I have accidentally run git clean -df. It removed my files from my current commit, which I had yet to push. Now, in git status, those files are marked with D, which means "deleted".

Is there any way to get those files back?

I have tried the following:

**git checkout** . and **git reset --hard**

and I get the following message:

git checkout .

fatal: Unable to create '/Users/lucia/.git/index.lock': File exists.
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.

❯ git reset --hard
fatal: Unable to create '/Users/lucia/.git/index.lock': File exists.

**Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.****

If I follow this path '/Users/lucia/.git/index.lock' on my computer, it doesn't exist.

Comment: `git clean` removes files that *aren't* version-controlled by Git. This won't result in any `D` status files as those are about files that *are* version-controlled by Git. Note, however, that since `git clean` removes files that *aren't in* Git, Git *cannot* get those files back. You need some non-Git software, such as any backup or Time Machine setup you might have, to get *those* files back.

Comment: Meanwhile, the D-status files *are* in Git and you *can* use Git to get them back. The error you're getting, though, suggests that something (perhaps a badly behaved Windows antivirus thing for instance) is preventing programs from doing *anything* on your computer; if so, disabling it might help. I don't use Windows but the people I know who do mostly say "don't use anything other than Windows Defender".